# Can't round number to two decimal places using floorf

Tags: c, floating-point, decimal, rounding

I found this formula here:

```
podrucje[i][j] = floorf(podrucje[i][j]  * 100 + 0.5)/100;
```

where `podrucje[][]` is float matrix. `floorf` returns correct value (`desired * 100`) but problem is with `/100`. For example if I have `49.599998`, `floorf` returns `4960.000` and after dividing by `100` result is again `49.599998`.

Where is the problem?

I know I can round it while printing but I'm going to use this matrix in Excel where it is converted to range thus i can't influence on representation.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: This is **the** standard reference for this question - though it could possibly be described as a teeny bit long and detailed! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Most decimal numbers aren't exactly representable as floats.

You probably need to either store them as integers, or do the rounding when converting to something humanly visible (i.e. printing the number out).

If you want to use the number for further calculations and need it to be rounded first, use a different representation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fundamental problem with the representation of floating point arithmetic which is not base-10!  You can *print* a base-10 with rounding to 2 decimal places though.

The standard safe way to export numbers safely across boundaries is through plain text ascii rather than as binary.